# Minus by row_number in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the data in the image. With the same id, I want to take the range of created_at by using "created_at" of the "row_number = 1" minus the "created_at" of "row_number = 2" and keep rolling from "row_number = 2" and "row_number = 3".

[image: 1]

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the approach below where I used [date_diff()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_diff) to get the difference in unit DAYS.

```sql
with sample_data as (
  select 989 as us_id, datetime('2019-08-17 13:51:34') as created_at
  union all select 989 as us_id, datetime('2020-03-01 08:11:41') as created_at
  union all select 989 as us_id, datetime('2020-03-01 10:21:20') as created_at
  union all select 989 as us_id, datetime('2020-05-27 14:39:28') as created_at
  union all select 990 as us_id, datetime('2019-07-10 20:38:22') as created_at
  union all select 990 as us_id, datetime('2019-07-12 08:41:23') as created_at
  union all select 990 as us_id, datetime('2019-07-16 19:34:31') as created_at
  union all select 990 as us_id, datetime('2019-08-06 07:48:45') as created_at
  union all select 990 as us_id, datetime('2019-08-08 10:36:05') as created_at
  union all select 990 as us_id, datetime('2019-08-09 13:49:58') as created_at
),
cte as (
select 
  *,
  row_number() over (partition by us_id) as rn,
from sample_data
),
cte2 as (
select 
  *, 
  lag(created_at) over (partition by us_id order by rn) as prev_created
from cte
)
select 
  us_id,
  created_at,
  prev_created,
  date_diff(created_at,prev_created,day) as created_at_diff
from cte2
```

Output:

[image]